# XA Transaction support in Coherence CE

Tags: caching, oracle-coherence

We have been using XA transactions in Coherence Enterprise Edition. But for the Coherence Community edition (Coherence CE), we don't see a document regarding XA transaction support. Does Coherence CE support XA transactions?

Answer (score 1):

No, Coherence CE doesn't support transactions.

Please see the following: https://coherence.community/latest/22.06/docs/#/docs/about/02_introduction

Also: https://github.com/oracle/coherence#documentation (table comparison)